# A question was flagged as 'Not suitable for this site' but points to 'Needs details or clarity'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, vote-to-close

I was reviewing for Close Votes on Stack Overflow. I had seen something viewable in a question:

[image: Stack Overflow Review Bug]

Notice that the question has been flagged as:

- Not suitable for this site

But pointed `2` (i.e. both flags) as **Needs details or clarity**. Is this a bug?

Comment: Not suitable for the site was a *flag* the 2 by needs details or clarity are *votes*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug.This means user with less than 3k reputation flagged the question as *Not suitable for this site* because of which the question got into review queue and there were 2 close votes for *Need details or clarity* from users with more than 3k reputation.

Comment: I had never seen different flags and different votes together.

Comment: @RohanBari - I see it hourly.